# Mysql query inside a query

Tags: php, mysql

First, apologies if the title doesn't match the question. Well, the problem is how to build this query...

I have a table called `category` It contains categories of my stuff(movies). It's like this...

```
--------------------------------
ID | name   | parent_category
--------------------------------
1  | love   | 0
2  | action | 0
3  | fear   | 0
4  | passion| 1
5  | danger | 2
6  | death  | 3
--------------------------------
```

So, as you see, each category has a parent category. Except the first 3. They're parents.

And movies table is like this...

```
--------------------------------
ID | name   | category
--------------------------------
1  | aaaa   | 1
2  | bbbbbb | 2
3  | cccc   | 2
4  | ddddddd| 1
5  | eeeeee | 3
6  | fffff  | 3
--------------------------------
```

So, what i want to do is, to select movies by parent category. Which means if I click category, `love`, it should select all the movies of categories that having `love` as the parent category.

So, how to write this in a single query ?

Comment: `select * from movies where category=1` .. it will display all movies in love category

Comment: How many levels of hierarchy can there be?

Comment: No, actually, in the movies table, movies are always saved with a child category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the parents are only one level deep, then you can use `join`s:

```
select m.*,
       coalesce(cp.id, c.id) as parent_id,
       coalesce(cp.name, c.name) as parent_name
from movies m left join
     categories c
     on m.category = c.id left join
     categories cp
     on c.parent_category = cp.id;
```

Actually, if you only want the `id`, you don't need two joins:

```
select m.*,
       (case when c.parent_id > 0 then c.parent_id else c.id end) as parent_id
from movies m left join
     categories c
     on m.category = c.id ;
```

Or, more simply:

```
select m.*, greatest(c.parent_id, c.id) as parent_id
. . .
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems little bit advanced stuff. Anyway I'll try. :)

Comment: In the answer, what is m means ?

Comment: `m` is a table alias.  It is an abbreviation for a table or subquery in the `from` clause.  In some cases, it is a convenience for writing and reading queries; in other cases (for `left join`s) it is a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

to select rows filtered by condition on secend table use join in FROM clause or subquery in condition with IN or EXISTS function. To compare field with some string you can use LIKE operator.

Answer (score 1):

If you are filtering based on parent_category -

```
SELECT b.*, a.name FROM movies b 
    LEFT JOIN categories a ON a.id = b.category
WHERE a.parent_category = 1;
```